# Interface for both Value and Reference types in a Generic

Tags: c#, generics

I am creating an Interface that will be implemented by classes which will be used as filters to create a query string. Each filter will be be responsible fr constructing a parameter in the query. The user can define whether to include the operator as well as what the operator shoudl be as well as the value. How the value is expressed depends on the datatype.

**Boolean:** " = 0"

**Integer:** " >= 2"

**DateTime:** " <> '2012-01-10'"

**String:** " = 'some string'"

```
public interface IFilter<T> 
{
    Nullable<T> Value { get; set; }
    String Operator { get; set; }
    Boolean IncludeOperator { get; set; }
}
```

This interface will be implemented by an abstract class which defines base fields, properties and overrides the ToString method; as well as an abstract GetValueAsString() method which shoudl be overriden to perform whatever logic required to contruct an appropriate string from the filter.

```
public abstract class Filter<T> : IFilter<T> 
{
    Nullable<T> _value;
    String _operator = "=";
    Boolean _includeOperator = false;

    public Nullable<T> Value { get { return this._value; } set { this._value = value; } }

    public String Operator { get { return this._operator; } set { this._operator = value; } }

    public Boolean IncludeOperator { get { return this._includeOperator; } set { this._includeOperator = value; } }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        String param = GetValueAsString();
        if (param != null && this.IncludeOperator)
            return this.Operator + " " + param;
        else if (param != null && !this.IncludeOperator)
            return param.Trim();
        else
            return null;
    }

    protected abstract String GetValueAsString();
}
```

I want to create typed filters derived from the interface and abstract class. Each filter will know how to convert a specific type into a string for inclusion in the query but each needs to adhere to the IFilter interface which it can do through it's inheritance of the Filter base class.

```
public class IntFilter: Filter<Int64>
{
    protected override string GetValueAsString()
    {
        // Convert the integer to a string
        return this.Value.Value.ToString();
    }
}

public class BooleanFilter : Filter<Boolean>
{
    protected override string GetValueAsString()
    {
        // convert the Boolean to a BIT value 1=True / 0=False
        return (this.Value.HasValue && this.Value.Value) ? "1" : "0";
    }
}

public class DateTimeFilter : Filter<DateTime>
{
    protected override string GetValueAsString()
    {
        // Convert the DateTime to a dateTime string in the following format - 2/27/2009 12:12:22 PM
        return (this.Value.HasValue) ? this.Value.Value.ToString("G") : null;
    }
}
```

Here's where it gets tricky ... I need to create a filter for a string type but using the same Interface and abstract class.

```
public class StringFilter : Filter<String>
{
    protected override string GetValueAsString()
    {
        // Convert the integer to a string
        return this.Value.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I need to be able to pass any of these filters into the following method ...

```
ExecuteQuery( IFilter filter );
```

You can see that there is a problem using a generic type for both a Reference and Value type. Does anyone have any idea how I can use this same interface for ALL the typed Filter classes? ***Is*** this possible?

Comment: Does the type of _value really need to be Nullable<T> ?

Comment: The filter must always return a value which is typically initialized to NULL. This may mean that the filters ToString method may return a string such as ... "= null". Since the calling method may be processing a list of these at a time I don't want the caller to be resposnsible for determining the state of the value then reacting. To be honest, however, I got stuck on the issues with inheritance and Nullable types that I had not considered changing that part of my logic. I will take a look at that. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add what you want the different outputs of ToString() to be? That might help me understand what you're goal is.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the Nullable<> out of the definitions and then pass them into the implementations. Here is an example:

```
public interface IFilter<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
    String Operator { get; set; }
    Boolean IncludeOperator { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Filter<T> : IFilter<T>
{
    T _value;
    String _operator = "=";
    Boolean _includeOperator = false;

    public T Value { get { return this._value; } set { this._value = value; } }

    public String Operator { get { return this._operator; } set { this._operator = value; } }

    public Boolean IncludeOperator { get { return this._includeOperator; } set { this._includeOperator = value; } }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        String param = GetValueAsString();
        if (param != null && this.IncludeOperator)
            return this.Operator + " " + param;
        else if (param != null && !this.IncludeOperator)
            return param.Trim();
        else
            return null;
    }

    protected abstract String GetValueAsString();
}

public class IntFilter : Filter<Nullable<Int64>>
{
    protected override string GetValueAsString()
    {
        // Convert the integer to a string
        return this.Value.HasValue ? this.Value.ToString() : "0";
    }
}

public class BooleanFilter : Filter<Nullable<Boolean>>
{
    protected override string GetValueAsString()
    {
        // convert the Boolean to a BIT value 1=True / 0=False
        return (this.Value.HasValue && this.Value.Value) ? "1" : "0";
    }
}

public class DateTimeFilter : Filter<Nullable<DateTime>>
{
    protected override string GetValueAsString()
    {
        // Convert the DateTime to a dateTime string in the following format - 2/27/2009 12:12:22 PM
        return (this.Value.HasValue) ? this.Value.Value.ToString("G") : null;
    }
}

public class StringFilter : Filter<String>
{
    protected override string GetValueAsString()
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value) ? "" : Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem that comes up with this solution is that when I evaluate "this.Value" (property for _value field) in the GetValueAsString() method I need to use "this.Value.HasValue" to determine if the value has been set, which would not be available if it was not a Nullable value. After removing the nullable from the abstract class I tried overriding the field and property definitions in the derived classes using nullable but get errors.(type must be 'long' to match overridden member 'Filter<long>.Value'). Is there another way to determine if a value type has not been set?

Comment: Because GetValueAsString is abstract and implemented in the child, at the compile time you will know what the real type is, therefore this implementation works in my tests.